# Copying a password into an array then compairing

Tags: c

I'm trying to get the password written into the file that the user types in, saved into an array, so that I may then compare what the user input is, and allow them to log in.
This is my code, must be ANSI Standard. at the moment I am not able to get the passwords to compare and give the correct output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAMELENGTHS 20
#define TEXTLENGTHS 200
#define PASSWORDS 7

struct patients
{
char forename[NAMELENGTHS];
char lastname[NAMELENGTHS];
int birthDay;
int birthMonth;
int birthYear;
float hight;
float weight;
char conditions[TEXTLENGTHS];
char medication[TEXTLENGTHS];
int vaxno;
char comments[TEXTLENGTHS];

};

void emptyBuffer(void);


int main(void)
{
FILE *fin;
char username[NAMELENGTHS];
char password[PASSWORDS];
char userInput[PASSWORDS];
printf("please enter a username: ");
scanf("%s", username);
emptyBuffer();
if(!(fin = fopen(username, "r")))
{
    printf("user not recognised\n");
    return 1;
}
while(!feof(fin))
{
    fgets(password, PASSWORDS, fin);
}
fclose(fin);
printf("Please enter a password: ");
scanf("%s", userInput);
emptyBuffer();
if(userInput == password)
{
    printf("Successful Login");
}
else
{
    printf("Login Failed please restart");
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}


void emptyBuffer(void)
{
while(getchar() != '\n')
{
    ;
}
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). Take inspiration from existing open source programs, e.g. [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: I haven't tested it, but they parameters you pass to `scanf` seem to be a little weird.

Comment: Why are you calling fopen twice on the same file?

Comment: yeah dont worry i changed that as soon as I uplpoaded

Comment: `int p; .. while(p < PASSWORDS)` That is Undefined Behaviour as `p` is an uninitialised variable.

Comment: `scanf("%20[^\n]PW.txt", username);` will not append "PW.txt" to `username` - which I think you are trying to do.

Comment: how would i scan for a username, and find the .txt file, sorry new to programing

Comment: i am also having trouble with getting the password out of the file, I have initiallised p as 0 now but it still crashes when the program is run

Comment: @MayhemDaes Please edit the question/post and upload your updated/current code

Comment: One too big:  `scanf("%20[^\n]PW.txt", username);` --> `scanf("%19[^\n]PW.txt", username);`

Comment: i have updated the question, but the password is still not giving the right outcome when I type in the correct password

Comment: Can you explain how the files are named and what their format is?

Comment: sure the files are .txt, and they each just have a word that is the password. the one I am using for testing is called "sayem.txt"

Answer (score 0):

You want to append ".txt" to the user name. You can use `strcat` for that. Also, use `strcmp` to compare strings.

```
printf("Enter user name: ");
// The -4 is to leave room for ".txt"
if (fgets(username, sizeof(username) - 4, stdin)) {
    // fgets leaves newline. remove it
    size_t len = strlen(username);
    if (len > 0 && '\n' == username[len - 1]) username[len - 1] = '\0';
    // Now append .txt
    strcat(username, ".txt");
    // Read the password
    if (!(fin = fopen(username, "r"))) {
        // Remove ".txt" for error message
        username[len - 1] = '\0';
        fprintf(stderr, "user \"%s\" not recognized\n", username);
        return 1;
    }
    // Read the password from the file
    if (fgets(password, sizeof(password), fin)) {
        len = strlen(password);
        if (len > 0 && '\n' == password[len - 1]) password[len - 1] = '\0';
        printf("Enter password: ");
        // Get the password from the user
        if (fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin)) {
            len = strlen(userInput);
            if (len > 0 && '\n' == userInput[len - 1]) userInput[len - 1] = '\0';
            // Compare
            if (0 == strcmp(userInput, password)) {
                puts("Successful Login");
            }
            else {
                fclose(fin);
                fputs("Login Failed please restart\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fin);
}
```